# Read colour of element below fixed position DIV

Tags: jquery

Is it possible in jQuery to look at the background colour of a DIV that is below a fixed position DIV? I have a fixed position headerbar at the top of a website with no background, which includes a logo with grey text - I have some DIVs in the content area with background colours of the same grey, so when they scroll up to sit below the logo, the logo is hard to see as the greys blend into each other. Is there a way in jQuery I can read the value of the background colour of the DIVs directly below the fixed position header bar DIV and change the image src accordingly to show a different coloured version of the logo?

Comment: Find all elements that are in same position, than sort them by z-index, than find first with background set.

Comment: There's various solutions to this issue on SO, have a look through: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=logo+color+change

Comment: I suggest to set some border for logo, so even grey on grey would be seen

Comment: I suggest to take a look at the javascript intersection observer api. With it, you can run functions once all included elements are visible (or not anymore). Instead of reading css values I would add body classes and hide/ show elements based on those classes

Comment: Thanks @Alex - that looks like a possible solution - just looking at https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/07/dynamic-header-intersection-observer/